# VB.NET - Duda con la declaracion If y su cierre End If

Tags: vb.net

Buenas, alguno me diría porque la declaracion **End If** no se la usa cuando abrimos con **Else If**?

```
If (num < 0) Then
    Console.WriteLine("El numero es negativo.")
ElseIf (num = 0) Then
    Console.WriteLine("El numero es 0.")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("El numero es positivo.")
End If

If (num = 0) Then
    Console.Write("Se ingresó el cero.")
Else
    If (num > 0) Then
        Console.Write("Se ingresó un valor positivo.")
    Else
        Console.Write("Se ingresó un valor negativo.")
    End If
End If
```

En el primero cuando uso **ElseIf** no es necesario cerrarlo con **End If**, por otra parte en el segundo cuando uso **Else** y "abajo" el **If**, ahí si necesito cerrarlo con un **End if**. Alguno me podría explicar por qué? Cuál de las dos soluciones debería usar?

Gracias.

Comment: Siempre debe cerrarse el **If**, de lo contrario resulta en error. El **End If** es siempre necesario. Asi del mismo modo para el resto de condicionales y ciclos.

Comment: El ElseIf no cuenta como If? En el primero que puse solo se cierra el If de afuera pero adentro se usa ElseIf y no parece que sea necesario?

Comment: Si, asi es. El **Else If** es como un nuevo **If**. Pero el **ElseIf** debe estar seguido de un **If**. Tal y como lo tienes en el primer ejemplo :)

Answer (score 0):

Porque el **Else If** es una condición adicional tal cual un **If** más, es por eso que puedes usar **Else** al final para contradecir a todas las condiciones que hayas escrito.